# How to get session variable in class Meta django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

```py
def getdb():
    print(request.session['process'])
    return request.session['process']
```

I need to access this function in class Meta: in django
I am not passing request as parameter, but I want to access session variable without request inside a function.

Comment: What is this `getdb` methods purpose and where are you calling it?

Comment: Its just the name of function

Comment: Why would you need to call it in a model's `Meta`? The `Meta` is usually static

Comment: I have multiple database tables with same columns  so I need to use single form class to save data to different tables,
I am dynamically fetching the table name
```python 
 class Meta:  
    def Leadx():  
            getdb()  
            return apps.get_model('leads', 'Lead')  
        model = Leadx()  
```

Comment: @RajanGupta you've to make use of request that was passed in form

Comment: @CharanjitSingh I cannot access request from class Meta in django from,
is there any way to access session variables without using request

Comment: You can query your database for sessions.